# How to change prediction in H2O GBM and DRF

Tags: python-3.x, random-forest, h2o, gbm

I am building a classification model in h2o DRF and GBM. I want to change probability of prediction such that if p0 <0.2 then predict= 0 else predict=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, you need to do this manually.  It would be easier if we had a `threshold` argument for the `predict()` method, so I created a [JIRA ticket](https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/PUBDEV-5734) ticket to make this a bit more straight-forward.

See a Python example below of how to do this manually below.

```
import h2o
from h2o.estimators.gbm import H2OGradientBoostingEstimator
h2o.init()

# Import a sample binary outcome train/test set into H2O
train = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_train_10k.csv")
test = h2o.import_file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/erin-data/higgs/higgs_test_5k.csv")

# Identify predictors and response
x = train.columns
y = "response"
x.remove(y)

# For binary classification, response should be a factor
train[y] = train[y].asfactor()
test[y] = test[y].asfactor()

# Train and cross-validate a GBM
my_gbm = H2OGradientBoostingEstimator(distribution="bernoulli", seed=1)
my_gbm.train(x=x, y=y, training_frame=train)

# Predict on a test set using default threshold
pred = my_gbm.predict(test_data=test)
```

Look at the `pred` frame:

```
In [16]: pred.tail()
Out[16]:
  predict        p0        p1
---------  --------  --------
        1  0.484712  0.515288
        0  0.693893  0.306107
        1  0.319674  0.680326
        0  0.582344  0.417656
        1  0.471658  0.528342
        1  0.079922  0.920078
        1  0.150146  0.849854
        0  0.835288  0.164712
        0  0.639877  0.360123
        1  0.54377   0.45623

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

Here's how to manually create the predictions you want.  More info on how to slice H2OFrames is available in the [H2O User Guide](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/slicing-rows.html).

```
# Binary column which is 1 if >=0.2 and 0 if <0.2
newpred = pred["p1"] >= 0.2 

newpred.tail()
```

Look at the binary column:

```
In [23]: newpred.tail()
Out[23]:
  p1
----
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
   0
   1
   1

[10 rows x 1 column]
```

Now you have the predictions you want.  You could also replace the `"predict"` column with the new predicted labels.

```
pred["predict"] = newpred
```

Now re-examine the `pred` frame:

```
In [24]: pred.tail()
Out[24]:
  predict        p0        p1
---------  --------  --------
        1  0.484712  0.515288
        1  0.693893  0.306107
        1  0.319674  0.680326
        1  0.582344  0.417656
        1  0.471658  0.528342
        1  0.079922  0.920078
        1  0.150146  0.849854
        0  0.835288  0.164712
        1  0.639877  0.360123
        1  0.54377   0.45623

[10 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thank You. Well I've already implemented this logic manually. Was looking for some attribute as you've rightly mentioned.

Comment: @Erin , Can we get the predicted probability for the train data instead of test data. We can do pred = my_gbm.predict(test_data=train) but rather just from training the model. Thanks

Comment: @Neo We save the training metrics, but not the training predictions.  So you will have to re-generate them using `my_gbm.predict(test_data=train)`.